# Landsat 7 - 8 surface reflectance bands from ESPA (LEDAPS)

Tags: landsat, usgs, reflectance, surface, terrset

I have downloaded some Level 1 and higher level imagery data including surface reflectance as well.

I should process these data in Idrisi (Selva) package.
The Level 1 images' pixel values are between 0-255. The surface reflectances' values are between 0-10000 (valid range, according to the XML metadata documentation). Unfortunately Idrisi can not interpret these values correctly. The Level 1 (DN) composits look just fine, whilest the composits (from same bands) of surface reflectance look very weak (pale). I aware the 0.0001 scale of SR, but its application did not help.

Please advise how could I overcome on this issue (might be by image enhancements, or reclass, or some transformation?).

Answer (score 1):

If your composite looks pale, dark or in any other unfriendly way, it means that the histogram of the data needs to be adjusted. Such adjustment basically change which values in the data should be displayed. Since you're using Idrisi you'll probably find instructions [here](http://uhaweb.hartford.edu/gatetutor/idrisi/improc3a.html), but also take a look at [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/stretch-function.htm) link, which I think makes it more clear which histogram stretching method to use.